# Issue with toggle button functionality in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

I have `shiny` app with a side panel and main panel. The main panel consist of a line graph and toggle button, to expand main panel and collapse side panel. Here, main panel doesn't expand as expected.
This what I get when tried to use toggle button inside the main panel.

[image]

I'm taking the main panel class to adjust the width by `css`. The size gets adjusted but has some interactivity issues.
Sample Code:

```
library(shiny)

library(plotly)

library(bsplus)
library(shinyjs)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$title("Toggle button not working properly"),
  ),
  tags$div(
    id = "sidebar",
    sidebarPanel(
      bs_accordion(
        id = "accordion"
      ) %>%
        bs_set_opts(
          use_heading_link = TRUE
        ) %>%
        bs_append(
          title = tags$div(id = "accordion_items", tags$div(id = "left_item_accordion", tags$i(class = "fa-solid fa-upload"), "Upload"), tags$div(id = "right_item_accordion", tags$i(class = "fa-solid fa-caret-down"))),
          content = fileInput("upload", "Upload a Excel File",
                              accept = c(".xlsx", ".csv")
          )
        ),
      actionButton("act_button1", "Bro"),
      use_bs_accordion_sidebar()
    )
  ),
  mainPanel(
    class = "mainPanel",
    id = "first-tab",
    actionButton("toggle_btn", "Toggle"),
    plotlyOutput("plot")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  

  
  bln <- reactiveValues(hidden = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input$toggle_btn, {
    shinyjs::toggle(id = "sidebar")
    
    if (!bln$hidden) {
      runjs('$(".mainPanel").css("width", "100%");')
      bln$hidden <- TRUE
    } else {
      runjs('$(".mainPanel").css("width","66.66%");')
      bln$hidden <- FALSE
    }
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly() %>%
      add_trace(
        x = seq(1, 100),
        y = rnorm(100),
        type = 'scatter',
        mode = 'lines',
        line = list(color = 'blue')
      ) %>%
      layout(
        annotations = list(
          list(
            x = 0.5,
            y = 0.5,
            text = "HI",
            showarrow = F,
            font = list(
              size = 20,
              color = "#e64d39"
            ),
            align = "center",
            xanchor = "center",
            yanchor = "middle"
          )
        ),
        xaxis = list(title = "X-axis title", showgrid = F, zeroline = F),
        yaxis = list(title = "Y-axis title", showgrid = F, zeroline = F),
        plot_bgcolor = "#FFFFFF"
      )
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```